# Basic assignment statement

Tags: c++

i'm a student of IT and i have some general academic knownledge of C. Recently i started to study C++ but i'm stuck to this strange thing i that found now about assignments.

1^ program:

```
int main() {
int x;

cout << x;
return 0;
}
```

> x is printed in stdout as 0.

2^ program:

```
int main() {    
    int x, y=2;

cout << x << endl << y;
return 0;
}
```

> x is printed in stdout as 1.

Anyone can explain me, please?

Thanks, Gabriele.

Comment: "*i have some general academic knownledge of C*" - are you aware of so-called *undefined behaviour*? It's the same in `C++`. What would happen if you did `int x; printf("%d", x);` in `C`?

Comment: C requires you to initialize any variable before you use it for deterministic behavior.

Comment: Please take a look at the following link to see how you can place your code nicely in a question https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Fureeish

no, i'm not. I just asked to have some comparison. Anyway i guess it will printed the random value assigned at runtime. I run this programs several times before asking here, and i got always the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Uninitialized local variables do not have a determined value. This usually depends on what's there in memory. Never use an uninitialized local variable.

Comment: That's not quite a *random value*. It's undefined behaviour. It's not even safe to assume that accessing a single, uninitialised variable twice will yield the same value.

Comment: @Gazi Alankus

Yes i always followed this rule while using C. I just doing some exercises and i found this.

Comment: If you got that code from somewhere, I think we can conclude that it's not a trustworthy source.